# Instanciar classe fora do namespace

Tags: php, classes, namespace

Tenho uma classe com o *namespace* definido:

```
namespace App;   
class AppSessionHandler {
    private $db;
    //...
    $this->db = Utils::ZendDB();  >>>>>> LINHA 12
}
```

O seguinte erro ocorre:

> Class 'App\Utils' not found in /Class/Utils/class.AppSessionHandler.php on line 12

A classe `Utils` não está incluída em nenhum *namespace*.

Como instancia-la dentro da classe `AppSessionHandler`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por estar dentro do *namespace* `App` ao instanciar a classe `Util` o PHP está procurando pela classe `App\Util`, que não existe. É preciso especificar que na verdade você deseja utilizar a classe `Util`.

Isso pode ser feito de duas formas:

Importe essa classe utilizando `use`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Utils;

class AppSessionHandler {

    private $db;

    //...

        $this->db = Utils::ZendDB();
}
```

Ou referencie o nome completo da classe a partir do escopo global (`\`):

```
<?php
namespace App;

class AppSessionHandler {

    private $db;

    //...

        $this->db = \Utils::ZendDB();
}
```

Caso você vá utilizar a classe `Util` em outros métodos da classe, o primeiro método é mais eficiente. No seu exemplo você está importando a classe `Util`, mas essa poderia ser uma classe de outro *namespace* como `Zend\Db\Connection\Utils`. Utilizar o `use` simplifica as proximas utilizações na classe pois não será necessário usar o nome completo da classe:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Zend\Db\Connection\Utils;

class AppSessionHandler {

    //...

        $this->db = Utils::ZendDB();
}
```

Se for utilizar essa classe somente uma vez, o nome completo a partir do global `\` já resolve. Porém não fica tão claro no inicio da classe a sua dependência com a classe `Utils`

Mais informações de como trabalhar com *namespaces* você pode consultar na [documentação<sup>en</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

Comment: ao colocar \NomeDaClasse (a barra no inicio) isso indica o que? Que não há namespace?

Comment: Só fiz uma correção no seu código, não é "using" e sim "use".

Comment: Filipe, enriqueci a resposta com mais alguns detalhes.

Comment: Depois de aprender este básico para uso de outros Namespaces, Filipe Moraes, veja com atenção a PSR-0 e PSR-4