# É possível fazer uma Classe ser acessível em todos namespaces?

Tags: php, namespace, spl

A pergunta é semelhante a esta [Instanciar classe fora do namespace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68197/3635) e tem uma boa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68198/3635

No entanto eu gostaria de fazer isto automaticamente. Por exemplo:

É possível fazer uma *Classe* ser acessível em todos namespaces? Sem usar `\` ou `use \Classe as Class;`.

Por exemplo, estou usando `spl_autoload_register` no *index.php*:

```
<?php
class Utils {
   public function example() {
      echo 'Olá mundo!';
   }
}

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    $relative_class = strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class));

    $file = './src/' . $relative_class . '.php';

    if (is_file($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
});

$user = new \Controllers\Foo\User;
```

Isto `new \Controllers\Foo\User;` autocarrega o arquivo *./src/controllers/foo/user.php*

user.php:

```
<?php
namespace Controllers/Foo;

class User
{
    public function foo() {
        //Something...
    }
}
```

Se eu precisar usar a classe *Utils* eu terei que adicionar no *user.php* algo como:

```
public function foo() {
   \Utils::example();
}
```

ou

```
<?php
namespace Controllers/Foo;

use \Utils as Utils;

class User
{
    public function foo() {
        Utils::example();
    }
}
```

- É possível fazer a classe **Utils** ser acessível a todos namespaces?
- Ou no momento que eu carrego uma classe pelo `spl_autoload_register` a classe `Utils` ser adicionada automaticamente ao atual namespace?

Eu quero usar a classe Utils sem precisar adicionar `use \Utils as Utils;` ou sem precisar de `backslash` (`\Utils::`), é possível?

Apenas a classe Utils, eu gostaria de usar assim:

```
<?php
namespace Controllers/Foo;

class User
{
    public function foo() {
        Utils::example();
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho que os namespaces já conseguem gerar confusão suficiente sem uma funcionalidade dessas...

Comment: @Oeslei Eu também estava confuso rs, agora estou com um pouco mais de compreensão, gostaria de uma opinião sua. Deixa explicar primeiro, o uso de namespaces vai além do psr-4 pra mim, eu quero poder criar classes com mesmo nome seguindo o padrão MVC e pra isto sem que de erro ao declara uma classe Modal e uma classe Controller com mesmo nome. Os controladores só funcionam dentro do `namespace Controller;` e os models dentro de `namespace Model;` outro motivo é eu poder criar controladores e models em subpastas e se por acaso o nome de uma classe repetir ainda sim estarão em namespaces ...

Comment: ... diferentes, então quando carrego um controlador assim `new \Controller\user\account;` ele não conflitará com isto `new \Model\user\account;` por exemplo. Eu estou relutante em usar "namespaces", pois eu vejo que raramente estes conflitos podem acontecer, já que geralmente só usamos um controlador por vez. Eu realmente não sei se este negócio de namespace é o melhor caminho :( o que você acha? @Oeslei

Comment: Gosto muito de namespaces: previnem conflitos de nomes, identificam com mais facilidade sua função (model, controle, etc.) e são extremamente úteis para a implementação de um autoloader eficiente. Sobre o que você falou sobre as classes de controle só serem carregadas por outras classes no namespace controller (o mesmo com o model) é o que você deseja que aconteça ou é como você entendeu?

Comment: Talvez eu expressei mal, quem carrega tudo é o autoloader, quem chama o Model é o controller e o controller é chamado pelas Rotas. Quando digo carregar me refiro a declarar, se eu não usa-se namespaces teria que criar um nome pra um model e outro nome pra um controlador. Mas é apenas um exemplo, nem sempre vou usar um model especifico com mesmo nome pra um controlador, eu posso usar quantos models eu quiser dentro de um action, até aonde entedi. A ideia de usar os namespaces é mais para organização e o desenvolvedor ter mais facilidade de entender a qual Controller pertence tal model @Oeslei

Comment: É mais um conceito de organização, mas estou relutante, estou preferindo seguir uma interface parecida com do laravel4, eu ainda estou relutante de tudo :(

Comment: Acredito que este tópico do SOen irá ajudar na escolha... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376462/laravel-5-namespaces

Comment: Obrigado @Oeslei vou ler :) - Enquanto isto http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80060/3635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe nada padrão pra fazer isto além de usar `use` ou `\`, no entanto podemos "trapacear" o php usando `eval` dentro do `spl_autoload_register` para extender a classe dentro do namespace.

```
<?php
class Utils {
   public static function example() {
      echo 'Olá mundo!';
   }
}

spl_autoload_register(function($class)
{
    $relative_class = strtolower(str_replace('\\', '/', $class));

    $file = './src/' . $relative_class . '.php';

    if (is_file($file)) {
        $np = explode('\\', $class); //Dividi string

        //Checa se a classe já existe no namespace especifico (previnir conflitos)
        if (class_exists(implode('::', $np)) === false) {

            //Remove o nome da classe, pois usaremos apenas o namespace
            array_pop($np);

            //executa um namespace dentro do eval "copiado" (estendendo a classe Utils)
            eval(
                'namespace ' . implode('\\', $np) . ' {' . PHP_EOL .
                'class Utils extends \Utils {}' . PHP_EOL .
                '}'
            );
        }

        require_once $file;
    }
});

$user = new \Controllers\Foo\User;
$user->foo(); //Irá exibir "Olá mundo!"
```

Admito que é uma gambiarra e talvez eu não venha a usar, mas é uma dica ainda sim.

> **Note:** Usar `use \Utils as Utils` não funciona dentro de `eval`