# PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?

Tags: mvc, php

Tenho dois códigos, o primeiro usa `spl_autoload_register` e o outro não, no entanto o segundo carrega "automaticamente a classe" também.

## Com spl_autoload_register

- Usa namespaces para dividir o MVC
- Pode-se criar vários níveis de pastas seguindo a ideia do [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)
- Controllers e Models podem ter o mesmo nome já que cada um está dentro de um namespace diferente.

Código:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
    $np = explode('\\', $class);

    $base = strtolower($np[0]);

    switch ($base) {
        case 'controller':
        case 'model':
            $base = 'application/' . $base . 's';
        break;
        default:
            return NULL;
    }

    array_shift($np);

    $relative_class = strtolower(implode('/', $np));

    $file = './' . $base . '/' . $relative_class . '.php';
    /*
     * resulta em algo como:
     * ./application/controllers/foo/test/user.php
     * ./application/models/foo/abc/user.php
     */

    if (is_file($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
});
```

Chamando um action de um controller:

```
$controller = new \Controller\foo\test\user;
$controller->profile();
```

Chamando um model:

```
$model = new \Model\foo\test\user;
```

---

## Com métodos

- Não usa namespaces
- "Eventualmente" pode ser mais fácil de entender/usar que o outro código anterior
- Controllers e Models não podem ter o mesmo nome, mas não é nenhum problema, já que podemos usar prefixos
- Suporta sub-pastas.

Código:

```
<?php
class App
{
    static private function prepare($path)
    {
        $fp = explode('.', $path);

        return array(
            'name' => end($fp),
            'path' => implode('/', $fp)
        );
    }

    static public function model($name)
    {
        $data = self::prepare($name);

        if (is_file($data['path'])) {
            require_once './application/models/' . $data['path'] . '.php';
        }

        return new $data['name'];
    }

    static public function action($name, $action)
    {
        $data = self::prepare($name);

        if (is_file($data['path'])) {
            require_once './application/controllers/' . $data['path'] . '.php';
        }

        $controller = new $data['name'];
        $controller->$action;
    }
}
```

Chamando um action de um controller:

```
App::action('foo.test.user', 'profile');
```

Chamando um model:

```
$model = App::model('foo.abc.user');
```

---

A minha duvida é, devo usar a maneira mais simples sem namespaces e `spl_autoload` ou não? Como posso trabalhar ou melhorar estes códigos para que torne o uso mais simples para o desenvolvedor final?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minha recomendação seria utilizar diretamente um *autoloader* que implemente a PSR-4, como o incluso no Composer. Além de ser um padrão já plenamente adotado na comunidade, a configuração é mais simples e não é preciso reinventar a roda.

Considerando que seus exemplos são para fins didáticos, tenho algumas considerações:

---

Utilizar *namespaces* e `spl_autoload_register` possibilita a criação de uma estrutura mais extensível para a aplicação. Em projetos pequenos é raro acontecer colisão com o nome de classes, mas ao começar a introduzir bibliotecas externas, a chance disso ocorrer aumenta.

O conceito de *namespaces* é comum em outras linguagens, como os *packages* no Java, *namespaces* no C#, o que torna o conceito já conhecido pelos desenvolvedores de *software*.

O `spl_autoload_register` faz o `require` das classes ou interfaces somente quando é necessários, inclusive ao fazer o `extends` ou `implements`.

Atualmente sua função do autoload só suporta as classes dentro de  `model` e `controller`, pois o case default dá um `return` no *autoload* sem retornar arquivo nenhum.

Eu retiraria o `switch` que adiciona o `s` aos controller e models e permitiria o autoload refletir exatamente o namespace das classes:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
    $np = explode('\\', $class);
    $relative_class = strtolower(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $np));

    $file = './' . $relative_class . '.php';

    if (is_file($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }
});
```

---

Apesar da segunda forma parecer atender suas necessidades, ela é mais limitada que utilizar o `spl_autoload_register`. Ela pode funcionar bem com *Models* ou *Controllers* simples, porém vejo os seguintes problemas:

- Refatorar a aplicação pode se tornar uma tarefa difícil, pois a referencia para a classe é uma `string` delimitada por pontos. Ao utilizar a referencia completa da classe podemos utilizar uma IDE para renomear essa classe e alterar suas referencias. Com uma `string` não vejo uma forma segura de fazer isso a não ser utilizando expressões regulares em todo o projeto ou um *replace all*. Existe inclusive uma constante incluída no [PHP 5.5 chamada `::class`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration55.new-features.php), que [retorna o caminho completo da classe](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class) com o *namespace* como *string*.
- A classe `App` não é exatamente um *autoloader*. Só são possíveis duas ações: retornar uma instância de determinado *model* ou executar a ação do *controller*. O PHP não irá carregar automaticamente as classes necessárias para a sua aplicação, limitado o uso de recursos da orientação a objetos, como herança e interfaces, a não ser que a classe pai ou a interface já tenha sido previamente incluída com um `require`, o que torna o código ainda mais complexo do que utilizar os `use` e *namespaces*. Veja esse exemplo considerando as classes a seguir

  ```
  // classe bar em ./application/controllers/bar.php
  class bar{

      public function run(){ echo "Hello World"; }

  }

  // classe baz em ./application/controllers/baz.php
  //
  // só é garantido que essa classe irá funciona se descomentar a linha abaixo
  // require_once 'application/controllers/bar.php';      
  class baz extends bar {}

  // arquivo principal

  // Executar esse método nesse momento resultará em um erro, pois a classe bar ainda foi carregada na aplicação
  //App::action('baz', 'run');

  // Isso vai funcionar como esperado, irá escrever na tela
  App::action('bar', 'run');

  // Agora baz vai funcionar pois bar já foi carregado na linha acima
  App::action('baz', 'run');
  ```

Comment: Poderia explicar este ponto *string simples fortemente acoplada a sua estrutura de pastas.*, com psr-4 não é quase a mesma coisa, só que namespaces acoplados a estrutura de pastas?

Comment: Eu também não entendi isto *O PHP não irá carregar automaticamente as classes necessárias para a sua aplicação*, ele carrega sim o arquivo .php automaticamente. Não entendi este ponto também.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta aqui com mais calma @GuilhermeNascimento.

Comment: Entendi agora, sobre isto *limitado o uso de recursos da orientação a objetos*, isto foi o ponto mais importante da sua resposta e com certeza o melhor, eu não sabia que isto `class Foo \Controller\exemplo {}` dispara o `spl_autoload`, testei e funcionou. -- falta minha ao ler a documentação do php rs

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo (sem a necessidade de escrever o código do spl) `class baz extends bar` explicando que `extends bar` também funciona com spl. Fora isto o meu primeiro código eu fiz com base no psr-4 ([Closure Example](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/#closure-example)), poderia fazer alguma sugestão/revisão/critica dele?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tudo bem em utilizar o clousure junto com o `spl_autoload_register `. O único comentário que tenho é que seu código não é compatível com versões entre o PHP 5.1 (onde foi introduzido a SLP) e a versão 5.3 (que é onde apareceram as clousures). Fora isso não vejo problemas.

Comment: mas eu testei o código no php5.3 e funcionou normal, só não funciona no php5.0 até o 5.1 pois estes não suportam *namespaces*.

Comment: Verdade, como são utilizados namespaces o código já requer que a versão minima seja a 5.3. Se fosse utilizar somente o spl_autoloader (sem o clousure) que seria suportado no 5.1 e 5.2

Comment: corrigindo meu ultimo comentário, 5.0, 5.1 e 5.2. :) Obrigado a dica do `extends`, `implements`, etc foi o que fez eu decidir.

Comment: Só pra comentar, então quando disse que funciona no 5.3 é que eu fiz *sem o clousure* depois. Obrigado