# Para que serve realmente namespace?

Tags: php, mvc, namespace

Gostaria de perceber a grande necessidade e utilidade de *namespaces* na arquitetura MVC.

Em que circunstanciais o uso de *namespaces* torna-se indispensável?

Dê um exemplo de um caso concreto se possível.

Comment: Relacionada: [PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80060/psr-4-em-um-projeto-mvc-ou-n%C3%A3o)

Comment: Cara, melhor do que responder com texto vou te indicar um vídeo. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAMwFTY1RLw

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss na verdade a minha duvida nao consiste no funciionamento de `namespace` mas sim nos casos critico em que ela torna-se indispensavel ... Nao pretendo usar simplesmente como uma **modinha** !

Comment: Mas é o funcionamento que define o caso crítico: conflito de nomes.

Comment: MVC nada tem a ver com namespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O principal uso dos *namespaces* é para organização e para evitar colisão de nomes de classes. O PHP não permite que duas classes tenham o mesmo nome, e para evitar esse problema tínhamos que criar classes muito específicas.

O motivador disso foi o inicio dos *frameworks* em PHP, que vinham como proposta de resolver problemas comuns no desenvolvimento. Só que isso limitava como criar nossas classes, pois não podíamos repetir nomes. A solução foi então criar classes muito específica, prefixando com o nome da sua aplicação.

Suponha que você esteja desenvolvendo uma classe `Service` para consultar o frete a partir de um CEP.

Criar uma classe que se chama `Service` pode conflitar com outro classe `Service` para envio de SMS.

Assim, ao invés de fazer isso:

```
App_ConsultCepService

App_SendSmsService
```

Com *namespaces* você pode fazer algo assim:

```
App\Cep\Service

App\Sms\Service
```

Isso também te ajuda a dividir seu software em interesses comuns, e também utilizar padrões de *autoloads* já consolidados com os principais projetos em PHP, como o PSR-4 que é implementado pelo Composer.

Para mais explicações veja:

[Como funciona namespaces no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/como-funciona-namespaces-no-php)

[PSR-4 em um projeto MVC ou não?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80060/psr-4-em-um-projeto-mvc-ou-n%C3%A3o)